# "No valid qt versions found" при создании проекта

Tags: qt, c++

Здравствуйте! Установил QT Creator 2.2 При создании проекта QT Gui Application пишет: No valid qt versions found ... Не могу ничего сделать. MinGW стоит в корне диска С. Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставить библиотеку QT. И указать Creator'у где она находится.

Comment: библиотека qt разве не идёт с creator'ом? и где же её взять?

Comment: Есть разные версии creator'а, с библиотекой и без. Библиотеку можно скачать с офф сайта qt.nokia.com

Answer (score 3):

Скачайте [SDK](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) и установите, там будет все необходимое, и креатор, и кутэ, и куча сэмплов.